# Problem compiling pgplots contour plot

Tags: pgfplots

I can not compile this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]% 
\addplot3[contour gnuplot]%
        coordinates {
            (0,0,0) (1,0,0)   (2,0,0)   (3,0,0)

            (0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)

            (0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

First I got an error message `plot file{test2_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened`. As per section 4.3.5 of pgfplots manual I added option `--shell-escape` when compiling but the error is still there. I am using TexWorks, added options `$synctexoption --shell-escape $fullname`. Thanks if anyone can help

Comment: Do you have `gnuplot` installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed but outdated, I am updating it now

Comment: Thank you Schrödinger's cat, I have updated gnuplot I ran it from the terminal but still get the same error when compiling pdflatex ?

Comment: Strange. I do not get an error if I compile your code on an updated TeXLive 2019 installation with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: It is strange, I tried to compile in Terminal I do not know what happens, terminal recognises pdflatex but do not recognise the class

Comment: Thaks a lot any way

Comment: You may have more than one latex installation. This happened to me once, and I had similar problems. You may try the usual tricks like `which pdflatex` and search for the document class to get a feeling for how many installations you have.

Comment: Yes I already tried and checked the paths, I will work this and if I come to a solution I will let you know